# Web Page crashes after 15 seconds after loading a very long text file

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, node-streams

so I am taking a Udemy class about NodeJs and the teacher gave us an example on how to use the "pipe()" method to transfer chunks of data so that the page would load better.
problem is that after about 15 seconds my webpage crashes with "AW SNAP!" error code 5.

the server is still on.
my guess is that google chrome is making this error because the data is too long,
but how can i be sure of that?

note: "test-file.txt" is just the string "node is awesome" 10k times

```
const fs = require("fs");
const server = require("http").createServer();

server.on("request", (req, res) => {
 const readable = fs.createReadStream("test-file.txt");
  readable.pipe(res);
});

server.listen(8000, "127.0.0.1", () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/`);
});
```

Comment: that's not a lot of data. And what is in the server logs?

Comment: I don’t know what are server logs, the server is still running the the terminal.

Comment: wrap your code in server.on("request, ...) in a try catch block, see if any errors occur. Also what is the endpoint you are trying to load in the browser?